# How to authentic connection using Mongoose to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I can't find this anywhere on the internet. I created a user in MongoDB in the MongoShell.

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "user" , pwd: "test", roles: [  "userAdminAnyDatabase","readWriteAnyDatabase" ]})
```

I used the MongoDB compass to login. It works, I can see every database and collections. But I wanted to login using Mongoose (A wrapper for MongoDB) for my NodeJS app. In the Mongoose version 5.4.19 documentation, it said that you can use `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');`
So I did this: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:test@localhost:27017/walnutz');` but it didn't work.
I also tried doing this:
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:test@127.0.0.1:27017/walnutz');`
but that didn't work as well. So does anyone have the answer to fix this issue?

Comment: Did not work how exactly? Show all the code you are running that reproduces whatever "didn't work" actually means.

Comment: Please post your exact error

Comment: (node:3860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.